# rails 3.2 renders RAW Javascript when URL is having .js extension

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having weird issue. I'm getting RAW Javascript Code when URL is having .js in URL.

http://www.test.com/documents.js?list_type=index&page=2

Any idea, why it is behaving like this?

```
def index 
  Query to fetch documents

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

on check-box click, calling a JQUERY to load Documents partial:

```
$.get('/documents.js', window.search_filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Likely because you have a file called documents.js in your public folder.

Rails will look in public for the requested file before it goes to your routes file.

Similar to when you have to remove index.html from public in order to get started on your app.

Comment: No - I dont have documents.js in my public folder